# javascript doesn't fire on new id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new here and I'm trying to code a little tool for myself, but I ran into a problem. I have searched but I can't find a proper solution. I even know what is the issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

I have a `<div>` that will cause , on click, to rename the `id` of another `<div>`. But after that, the `<div>` with the new `id` isn't able to reach or fire any event.

Here is a code example for my problem.

**html:**

```
<div id="example1">click me</div>
<div id="example2">click me, too.</div>
```

**js:**

```
$('#example1').click(function () {
  $('#example2').attr('id', 'exampleX');
  console.log("done X");
});


$('#exampleX').click(function () {
  $('this').attr('id', 'example2');
  console.log("undone X");
});
```

The first click event is working fine, but the second is not responding, I guess it is because the DOM has already loaded and doesn't know the new `<div>`.

How can I fix it?

Any help is much appreciated . 
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have to change the `id`, because I build a little tool or game that changes the `<img>` of a `<div>` based on the `<div>`s clicked earlier. At this point the failure accrues when a *"blank `<div>`"* with a placeholder `<img>` changes the `<img src>` and has to store some information in a val, what it doesn't because I can't fire any event on click. Changing the id has to be done to know which information needs to be stored in the `var`.

Comment: The top level `$('#example1')` and `$('#exampleX')` run when the page is loaded. `$('#exampleX')` silently fails (because JQuery doesn't throw errors when elements are missing). If you want to run `$('#exampleX')` after changing the element's ID, you should add that code into the click handler for `#example1`.

Comment: Ok let's back it up here, why are you changing the ids of elements?

Comment: You should rewire the event handlig on `#example2` after you change its ID into `#exampleX`

Comment: `#exampleX` does not exist when the script is parsed. @Halcyon asked a real good question: Why are you changing the `id`? We may suggest you something else to achieve what you want. [**That is an X/Y problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic unless it is edited. This definitely is an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) useless for other readers in the future.

Comment: i have to change the id, because i build a little tool or game that changes the img of a div based on the divs clicked earlier. At this point the failure accrues when a "blank div" with a placeholder img changes the img src and has to store some information in a val, what it doesn't because i can't fire any events on click.

Comment: You could just use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which handles an event only once. Changing the `id` is a bad idea (pun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your Jquery code. Bind the function for clicking on `#exampleX` after changing the elements id to `#exampleX`.

```
var click_function = function(){
   $('this').attr('id', 'example2');
   console.log("undone X");
};

$('#example1').on("click", function(){
    $('#example2').attr('id', 'exampleX');
    console.log("done X");

    $('#exampleX').off("click").on("click",click_function);
});
```

This is what you are asking for.
https://jsfiddle.net/8skz9pwr/2/

Changing the ID of an element is not clean coding. I think there are much better ways to achive what you want but this answers your question.

Comment: `$('#exampleX').unbind("click");` is useless since it isn't binded anyway. And [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is depreceated... Better use `.on()` and `.off()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I changed my solution. Is it ok now?

Comment: Close... Again, `.off("click")` is useless since there was no handler attached to `#exampleX`.

Comment: Yes, but if you click multiple times on `#example1` I would attach the handler multiple times to `#exampleX`. It is only useless for the first click on `#example1`. Am I not right?

Comment: Ha. Ok I get your idea. And you're right. ;) So guessing that this is close to what OP expects... +1

Comment: Ok :) Thanks anyways for thinking about and helping with my answer.

Comment: Thanks Louys and Nope, I appreciated your suggestions. But I definitively asked wrong about my problem. I tried to work like written in my question for several levels like a self-building tournament tree. But to know that changing the id is a bad idea i try something else to solve my problem.